# Include sorted non-repeating random list of pdfs

Tags: latex3

I am trying to create a file that can generate a random, non-repeating, sorted list of numbers so that I can generate various sets of homework assignments. I managed to find a way to generate a random sequence in latex3, but I am having trouble figuring out how to sort the thing. Here is the Latex3 code for generating the list:

```
%enable the latex3 coding language
\ExplSyntaxOn

% just for using all items
\NewDocumentCommand{\myforeach}{m +m}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
%%%%

\NewDocumentCommand{\declarerandomlist}{mO{1}m}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = start point (default 1)
  % #3 = end point
  \egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usefromrandomlist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = template
  \egreg_randomlist_use:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn
{
  \seq_clear_new:c { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
  \bool_do_until:nn { \int_compare_p:n { \seq_count:c { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq } = #3-#2+1 } }
   {
    \seq_put_left:cx { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq } { \int_rand:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
    \seq_remove_duplicates:c { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
   }

}


\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_randomlist_use:nn
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__egreg_randomlist:n { #2 }
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { randomlist } { exhausted } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:cN { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq } \l__egreg_randomlist_item_tl
    \__egreg_randomlist:V \l__egreg_randomlist_item_tl
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__egreg_randomlist_item_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_randomlist:n { } % initialize
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__egreg_randomlist:n { V }

\msg_new:nnn { randomlist } { exhausted } {List ~ #1 ~ exhausted}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\randomincludefile}[3]{%
% #1 = list name
% #2 = name before numbering system
\usefromrandomlist{#1}{\input{\string#2##1.tex}}
}
```

The issue arises in the \cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn method. I would like to sort the sequence l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq after I have generated it, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do this. I tried using \seq_sort, but my compiler does not seem to like the way that I have done this. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer provides new code that doesn't require to sort the sequence at all because it is built sorted. For code that does sort a sequence see below.

## Building a random sorted sequence

The code shown here will build a sorted sequence containing all numbers in a specified number range. Then it'll randomly remove items from that sequence until the required number of items is left. This way we do not need any sorting and still get a random subsample of your range with each element being unique. The code doesn't need the computationally expensive functions `\seq_remove_duplicates:N` and `\seq_sort:Nn` so should perform much better than the code presented in your question.

```
\documentclass{article}

%enable the latex3 coding language
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l__peabody_random_seq
\int_new:N \l__peabody_items_int
\int_new:N \l__peabody_length_int

\msg_new:nnn { peabody } { range-too-small }
  { range~ [#2,~#3]~ too~ small~ for~ random~ list~ with~ #1~ elements }
\msg_new:nnn { peabody } { unknown-seq } { no~ seq~ with~ name~ #1~ defined }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__peabody_set_random_seq:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    % #1: number of subset elements
    % #2: start of range
    % #3: end of range
    \int_set:Nn \l__peabody_items_int {#1}
    \int_set:Nn \l__peabody_length_int { #3 - (#2) + \c_one_int }
    \seq_clear:N \l__peabody_random_seq
    \int_compare:nNnT \l__peabody_items_int > \l__peabody_length_int
      {
        \msg_error:nnxxx { peabody } { range-too-small }
          { \int_eval:n{#1} }
          { \int_eval:n{#2} }
          { \int_eval:n{#3} }
      }
    % build a sorted sequence with the full range
    \int_step_inline:nnn {#2} {#3}
      { \seq_put_right:Nn \l__peabody_random_seq {##1} }
    % remove the extra items (randomly)
    \int_step_inline:nnnn
      \l__peabody_length_int
      { -1 }
      { \l__peabody_items_int + \c_one_int }
      {
        \seq_pop_item:NnN
          \l__peabody_random_seq { \int_rand:n {##1} } \l_tmpa_tl
      }
    % result is sorted
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \peabody_loop_random_seq:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    % #1: number of subset elements
    % #2: start of range
    % #3: end of range
    % #4: code to do on each element
    \__peabody_set_random_seq:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__peabody_random_seq {#4}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \loopoverrandomsubsetofrange { m O{1} m +m }
  { \peabody_loop_random_seq:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \peabody_set_named_random_seq:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    % #1: name
    % #2: number of subset elements
    % #3: start of range
    % #4: end of range
    \__peabody_set_random_seq:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4}
    \seq_clear_new:c { l__peabody_ #1 _random_seq }
    \seq_set_eq:cN { l__peabody_ #1 _random_seq } \l__peabody_random_seq
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \setrandomsubsetofrange { m m O{1} m }
  { \peabody_set_named_random_seq:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \peabody_loop_named_random_seq:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { l__peabody_ #1 _random_seq }
      { \seq_map_inline:cn { l__peabody_ #1 _random_seq } {#2} }
      { \msg_error:nnn { peabody } { unknown-seq } {#1} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \userandomsubsetofrange { m +m }
  { \peabody_loop_named_random_seq:nn {#1} {#2} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setrandomsubsetofrange{files}{50}[0]{100}% 50 random items in [0, 100]
\newcommand\randomincludefile[2]
  {%
    % #1: list name
    % #2: name before numbering system
    \userandomsubsetofrange{#1}{\input{#2##1.tex}}%
  }

\begin{document}
\userandomsubsetofrange{files}{#1, }

\loopoverrandomsubsetofrange{10}[0]{20}{#1, }
\end{document}
```

---

## Sorting a sequence

The following extends the macro `\egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn` to also sort the sequences once they're built.

```
%enable the latex3 coding language
\ExplSyntaxOn

% just for using all items
\NewDocumentCommand{\myforeach}{m +m}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
%%%%

\NewDocumentCommand{\declarerandomlist}{mO{1}m}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = start point (default 1)
  % #3 = end point
  \egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usefromrandomlist}{mm}
 {% #1 = list name
  % #2 = template
  \egreg_randomlist_use:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn
  {
    \seq_clear_new:c { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
    \bool_do_until:nn { \int_compare_p:n { \seq_count:c { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq } = #3-#2+1 } }
     {
      \seq_put_left:cx { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq } { \int_rand:nn { #2 } { #3 } }
      \seq_remove_duplicates:c { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
     }
     \seq_sort:cn { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
      {
        \int_compare:nNnTF {##1} > {##2}
          \sort_return_swapped:
          \sort_return_same:
      }
  }


\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_randomlist_use:nn
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__egreg_randomlist:n { #2 }
  \seq_if_empty:cTF { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { randomlist } { exhausted } { #1 }
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:cN { l_egreg_randomlist_#1_seq } \l__egreg_randomlist_item_tl
    \__egreg_randomlist:V \l__egreg_randomlist_item_tl
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__egreg_randomlist_item_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_randomlist:n { } % initialize
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__egreg_randomlist:n { V }

\msg_new:nnn { randomlist } { exhausted } {List ~ #1 ~ exhausted}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\randomincludefile}[3]{%
% #1 = list name
% #2 = name before numbering system
\usefromrandomlist{#1}{\input{\string#2##1.tex}}
}
```

But since your random sequence builder is building all the numbers in the range into that sequence, just in a shuffled manner, this is essentially the same as building a sequence ranging from 0 to 10 in the first place... So with `\egreg_randomlist_declare:nnn {foo} {0} {10}` you'd always get the same result, namely a sequence containing the elements 0, 1, 2, ..., 10.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick and detailed response! This was exactly what I was looking for! Also, I appreciate the notes on the code performance. I'm still pretty new to the latex3 language, so I'm still trying to figure out all of the things that I can do.

Comment: @peabody well, the code performance would be poor in any language, removing duplicates is necessarily at least O(n^2), sorting is O(n*log(n)) (the latter is quite good, but we should manage to have better performance, in theory the random sequence builder presented here should have something in the order of O(n) -- but don't nail me down to it -- depends how expensive resizing of arrays is).

Comment: @peabody please also note that if you want a shuffled sequence of every number in a range, I think using `\int_map_inline:nnn {<start>} {<stop>} { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1} } \seq_shuffle:N \l_tmpa_seq` should be faster than the code of your question (which most likely is older than the `\seq_shuffle:N` function).